# Prefetch maven-metadata.xml with nexus

Tags: maven, maven-3, nexus, maven-metadata

With the maven3 configuration file `settings.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
  <!--<host>webproxy</host>-->
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://richter-local.de:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>nexus</id>
        </server>
    </servers>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
      <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>interval:10080</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>interval:10080</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
     <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>interval:10080</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>interval:10080</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
  <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>
  <usePluginRegistry>false</usePluginRegistry>
  <offline>false</offline>
</settings>
```

and a nexus maven proxy (version 2.7.2-03) I have to wait for a bunch of very slow downloads of `maven-metadata.xml` file every day after 00:00 a.m. (take about 5 mintues together for some KB which ought to be transfered within seconds). How can I prefetch those file in order to download them my local nexus instance?

Comment: are your builds requesting lots of snapshot dependencies?

Comment: I'm fetching some snapshots (2 of 50 dependencies) and I would like to handle them as well, i.e. prefetch the data necessary to skip the slow downloads.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have one or more proxy repositories that have remotes that are responding very slowly.  Once a day the cache timeouts for these expires, resulting in very slow retrieval.

See here for information on how to debug this, and configure Nexus to prevent the issue from occurring again:

https://support.sonatype.com/entries/25884097-Troubleshooting-slow-maven-metadata-xml-download-speeds

Comment: After some experiments with the settings "metadata max age" and "not found cache ttl" I guess that the solution to set them to a higher value will not solve my problem because no prefetching occurs (it doesn't matter whether the issue happens twice a day or once a week). I want the slow actions to be anticipated by the proxy, i.e. nexus, and to be executed in not time when they are requested.